# Integrate SoapUI with TeamCity - TeamCity waiting on a condition

Tags: continuous-integration, soapui

I am trying to integrate SoapUI with TeamCity.

I have a working MSBuild file (works fine on the TC server when launched via the UI or command line), but when running the build from TeamCity it hangs and the [the Java thread dump](https://paste.ee/p/XoIO7#uUo75TbOTzV6MmUoceVCToTqqbffZx1X) returns a message stating that it is waiting on a condition (below). I am not sure why this is happening as when running the MSBuild outside of teamcity there are no errors that would seem to be connected problems on [the output](https://paste.ee/p/P2Zvz#MJxR1DzEwr0eMLMUSDm2JsbWqna7l7Wm). I think there may be a deadlock between TC and SoapUI, but unfortunately, I am not sure how to resolve this.

If anyone could shed any light on what this might be it would be greatly appreciated.